# Docker says it cannot remove images because a container is running but no containers are running

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In short:
I want to remove a docker image, but if I do so it tells me that it cannot be removed because the image is being used by a running container. But as far as I can tell there is no container running at all.

In detail:
I call `docker images -a` to see call images. This way I determine the Image ID which I want to delete and call `docker image rm {ID}` where {ID} is the String which should be deleted (it worked for other images so I am pretty confident so far).
I get the response:

*Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete {ID} (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 08815cd48523*
(The ID at the end seems to change with every call)

This error appears to be pretty easy to understand, but if I call `docker ps -a`, it shows me that I do not have a single container running and therefore no container running with the specified ID.

This problem occurs with some images. But all seem to be related to Kubernetes.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

As asked for in the comments hear docker inspect on one of the invisible containers (I replaced all part where I was not sure if it contains sensetive data with "removed_for_post"):

```
[
    {
        "Id": "Removed_for_post",
        "Created": "2021-10-05T07:04:33.2059908Z",
        "Path": "/pause",
        "Args": [],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 3570,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2021-10-05T07:04:33.4266642Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:80d28bedfe5dec59da9ebf8e6260224ac9008ab5c11dbbe16ee3ba3e4439ac2c",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ Removed_for_post /resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ Removed_for_post /hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ Removed_for_post /hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/ Removed_for_post / Removed_for_post -json.log",
        "Name": "/k8s_POD_etcd-docker-desktop_kube-system_ Removed_for_post ",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "host",
            "Dns": null,
            "DnsOptions": null,
            "DnsSearch": null,
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": -998,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": [
                "no-new-privileges"
            ],
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 2,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "/kubepods/kubepods/besteffort/removed_for_Post",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ Removed_for_post -init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ Removed_for_post /diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/Removed_for_post /merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/Removed_for_post /diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/Removed_for_post /work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "docker-desktop",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.2",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/pause"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "annotation.kubeadm.kubernetes.io/etcd.advertise-client-urls": "https://192.168.65.4:2379",
                "annotation.kubernetes.io/config.hash": " Removed_for_post ",
                "annotation.kubernetes.io/config.seen": "2021-10-05T07:04:32.243805800Z",
                "annotation.kubernetes.io/config.source": "file",
                "component": "etcd",
                "io.kubernetes.container.name": "POD",
                "io.kubernetes.docker.type": "podsandbox",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.name": "etcd-docker-desktop",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.namespace": "kube-system",
                "io.kubernetes.pod.uid": "removed for Post",
                "tier": "control-plane"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": " Removed_for_post",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": " Removed_for_post ",
                    "EndpointID": " Removed_for_post ",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]``
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the docker daemon? Sometimes things like this happen.

Comment: have you tried restarting the docker daemon? maybe there's some lingering data that would be deleted after the restart

Comment: The container is not running ... but it's in stopped state. Remove it using `docker rm 08815cd48523`. Now you can remove the image.

Comment: Restarting docker did not help. The container is also not in stopped state (```docker ps -a``` should show these because of the ```-a```). ```docker rm 08815cd48523``` also did not work

Comment: Could this be connected to DockerDesktop [build in kubernetes] (Windows/Mac) or are you using just docker (Linux)?

Comment: I am using DockerDesktop on Windows. So it could be related.

Comment: Did you try `docker rm -f 08815cd48523`? (`-f` option to force)?

Answer (score 1):

Your container seems to be created by an other tool like docker-compose as I guess it is local on your computer..

Which means you can not stop its creation with docker rm statement easily.

### EDIT 1 - Kubernetes

- You seems to be using docker desktop
- Your container seems to be `etcd` which is part of kubernetes master system (very important) :

> k8s_POD_etcd-docker-desktop_kube-system_ Removed_for_post

So, as it is part of kubernetes components, you should remove it only if you want to not use kubernetes.

> By removing kubernetes or etcd pod.

If docker-desktop, should not be a problem.

To summarize, `your container is created by a pod which is a resource handled by kubernetes`

### docker-compose

- find your docker-compose directory, usually containers names start with project name and go int its directory.
- execute `docker-compose down`

### docker

- Try to restart docker daemon,
  for instance in a linux based environment :
  `sudo systemctl restart docker`
- A reboot of your machine should works too.

Finally you should be able to remove containers as proposed in your question.

Comment: Hello, yes while I do not have docker-compose installed it seems likely that some other program created the container. Is there a way how I can find out which programm is using this image?

Comment: Hello, You may try to do this in the short time frame where it is running : `docker update <container name> --restart=unless-stopped`, then stop and remove it

Comment: There seems to be some mechanism which reinstalls deleted images... I managed to remove one of the images (as you described above), but the image reappeared and could not be deleted again as it again has some invisible containers.